# Global filter for Doctrine for Laravel

Tags: laravel, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine for Laravel (Laravel 5.7) and I want to implement a global filter instead of adding manually to each query 'where active = true'.

I heard about the SQL filters and came up with this class :

```
namespace App\Doctrine\Filters;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Filter\SQLFilter;

class ActiveFilter extends SQLFilter
{
    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
    {
        return sprintf('%s.active = %s', $targetTableAlias, $this->getParameter('active'));
    }
}
```

Then, in my main Controller (all my controllers extend from this one) :

```
public function __construct($em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;

        // Only display active rows.
        $this->em->getFilters()
            ->enable('active_rows')
            ->setParameter('active', true);
    }
```

I assume this is correct but then I'm not sure at all. As I have Doctrine for Laravel, i couldn't follow the tutorial I found [here (symfonycasts)](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-queries/filters). I didn't find anything in the documentation about it for Laravel.

So I edited my config/doctrine.php :

```
'filters' => [
            'active_rows' => 'app\Doctrine\Filters\ActiveFilter'
        ],
```

When I try this code I got this :

**Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'app/Doctrine/Filters/ActiveFilter' not found**

As required I provided the full namespace, I don't find the error. I think the path is correct. Am I missing something ?

Do you have an idea ?

Thanking you in advance,

Comment: can you change `app` to `App` in your `config/doctrine.php` or use `\App\Doctrine\Filters\ActiveFilter::class`

Comment: I tried with App, with and without ::class. But  I get the same error. Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class '\App\Doctrine\Filters\ActiveFilter::class' not found

Comment: if your namespace is correct, try running `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: It works now thanks to the command. The thing is I ran it before. But it's fully working now ! Thank you.